# Using a parameter as part of a SQL query inside stored procedure Oracle [homework]

Tags: oracle, parameters, sqlplus, procedure

I am a bit confused about Stored procedures and using cursors to run SELECT for multiple rows. I have a need to use the LIKE clause inside a SQL query. I have tested that this is in fact working with my stored procedure:

```
SQL> /* THIS WORKS*/
SQL> create or replace procedure search_testimonials(
  2  curRETURN OUT sys_refcursor
  3  )
  4  IS
  5  begin
  6   OPEN curRETURN FOR 
  7   SELECT testimonial
  8   FROM testimonial
  9   WHERE testimonial like '%like%';
 10  END search_testimonials;
 11  /

Procedure created.

SQL> variable buffer refcursor;
SQL> execute Search_Testimonials(:buffer);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print buffer;

TESTIMONIAL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
I like the way OAG does business. I will be a repeat customer
I like the Cashier named David. I think he is a hottie! Go AOGS
```

The problem arises when I try to use a parameter as part of my search term:

```
SQL> /* THIS DOES NOT WORK*/
SQL> create or replace procedure search_testimonials(
  2  search_term IN varchar2,
  3  curRETURN OUT sys_refcursor
  4  )
  5  IS
  6  begin
  7   OPEN curRETURN FOR 
  8   SELECT testimonial
  9   FROM testimonial
 10   WHERE testimonial like search_term||'%%';
 11  END search_testimonials;
 12  /

Procedure created.

SQL> 
SQL> execute Search_Testimonials('like', :buffer);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print buffer;

no rows selected
```

I have no idea why this does not work. I have also tried to use the @VARIABLE notation to pass the proper term. I am using SQLPlus to run the code. Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
 WHERE testimonial like search_term||'%%'
```

to

```
 WHERE testimonial like '%'|| search_term||'%'
```